# How to compute the numerical difference between columns of different dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given two spark dataframes A and B with the same number of columns and rows, I want to compute the numerical difference between the two dataframes and store it into another dataframe (or another data structure optionally).

For instance let us have the following datasets

DataFrame A:

```
+----+---+
|  A | B |
+----+---+
|   1|  0|
|   1|  0|
+----+---+
```

DataFrame B:

```
----+---+
|  A | B |
+----+---+
|   1| 0 |
|   0| 0 |
+----+---+
```

How to obtain B-A, i.e

```
+----+---+
| c1 | c2|
+----+---+
|   0| 0 |
|  -1| 0 |
+----+---+
```

In practice the real dataframes have a consequent number of rows and 50+ columns for which the difference need to be computed. What is the Spark/Scala way of doing it?

Comment: The general case with n columns has not been addressed yet, do you a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the approach below. This code can work with any number of columns. You just have to change the input DFs accordingly.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df0 = Seq((1, 5), (1, 4)).toDF("a", "b")
val df1 = Seq((1, 0), (3, 2)).toDF("a", "b")

val columns = df0.columns
    val rdd = df0.rdd.zip(df1.rdd).map {
      x =>
        val arr = columns.map(column =>
          x._2.getAs[Int](column) - x._1.getAs[Int](column))
        Row(arr: _*)
    }

spark.createDataFrame(rdd, df0.schema).show(false)
```

**Output generated:**

```
df0=>
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |5  |
|1  |4  |
+---+---+
df1=>
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |0  |
|3  |2  |
+---+---+
Output=>
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|0  |-5 |
|2  |-2 |
+---+---+
```

Comment: This answer is good, but do not generalize to the case with n columns. If you manage you generalize it I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I have updated the code. It is generic now. Please check and let me know if it works. Also, do accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your df A is the same as df B you can try below approach. I don't know if this will work correct for large datasets, it will be better to have id for joining already instead of creating it using `monotonically_increasing_id()`.

```
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df0 = Seq((1, 0), (1, 0)).toDF("a", "b")
  val df1 = Seq((1, 0), (0, 0)).toDF("a", "b")

  // new cols names
  val colNamesA = df0.columns.map("A_" + _)
  val colNamesB = df0.columns.map("B_" + _)

  // rename cols and add id
  val dfA = df0.toDF(colNamesA: _*)
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  val dfB = df1.toDF(colNamesB: _*)
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

  dfA.show()
  dfB.show()

  // get columns without id
  val dfACols = dfA.columns.dropRight(1).map(dfA(_))
  val dfBCols = dfB.columns.dropRight(1).map(dfB(_))

  // diff between cols
  val calcCols = (dfACols zip dfBCols).map(s=>s._2-s._1)

  // join dfs
  val joined = dfA.join(dfB, "id")
  joined.show()

  calcCols.foreach(_.explain(true))

  joined.select(calcCols:_*).show()
```

```
    +---+---+---+
    |A_a|A_b| id|
    +---+---+---+
    |  1|  0|  0|
    |  1|  0|  1|
    +---+---+---+

    +---+---+---+
    |B_a|B_b| id|
    +---+---+---+
    |  1|  0|  0|
    |  0|  0|  1|
    +---+---+---+

    +---+---+---+---+---+
    | id|A_a|A_b|B_a|B_b|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|
    |  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
    +---+---+---+---+---+

    (B_a#26 - A_a#18)
    (B_b#27 - A_b#19)

    +-----------+-----------+
    |(B_a - A_a)|(B_b - A_b)|
    +-----------+-----------+
    |          0|          0|
    |         -1|          0|
    +-----------+-----------+
```