# How do I divide one column in one df by another column in a different df in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my [image: example]

If I have two dataframes (say df4avg and df5avg) with identical corrected wavelengths and different count rates, and I want to divide the df4avg count rate by df5avg's count rate and get an output of the corrected wavelength and the new divided value with a new column name (say 'ratio'), how would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: If same values `wavelengths` values and same index values in both you can try `df4avg['count rate'] / df5avg['count rate']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute the numerical difference between columns of different dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525709/how-to-compute-the-numerical-difference-between-columns-of-different-dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the `ratio` column in the `df4avg` Dataframe then

```
df4avg['ratio'] = df4avg['COUNT_RATE'] / df5avg['COUNT_RATE']
```